# Centering a JFrame?

Tags: java

I'm using one of the methods to try to center my frame called

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

but it's centering it by putting the upper-right corner of the frame in the center of the screen, and that's not what I wanted. I wanted to make it so that it centers the frame itself in the middle, or in other words, I want the center of the frame to the in the center of the screen. Is there any other methods to do this? Thanks for the help.

More codes below:

```
 @Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
} //I'm using this method to override the Jframe and return the panel size
```

and I'm using the:

```
frame.pack();
```

method to make the Jframe fit whatever size the jpanel size is, which is why a size isn't created for the jframe. But even if I do create the size for the jframe, and use the setLocationRelativeTo(null) method, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you're using Java 1.4 or newer the method setLocationRelativeTo(null) should help. It's weird that it reacts like that, could you maybe post your java file so we can see what's wrong?

Also, you have to setSize() your frame BEFORE using the setLocationRelativeTo(null) method.

Kindly,
Solid

Comment: 1+ @Skillet, there is no need to check out your posted code, the answer to your problem has been given. The order of your code should be frame.pack(), frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null), frame.setVisible(true). The setLocationRelativeTo(...) method only works when the frame has a non-zero size.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of your screen with `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()`. Assuming you're not using multiple displays, it's simple from there to set the location of your JFrame such that it is centered in the screen.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Label"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();

    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    f.setLocation((screen.width - f.getWidth())/2, (screen.height - f.getHeight())/2);

    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

It is important that the `pack()` call happens before `setLocation`, or it might not be centered again.

You could even create a subclass of `JFrame` that re-centers itself whenever it packs, as such:

```
class CenteredFrame extends JFrame{
    @Override
    public void pack(){
        super.pack();
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation((screen.width - getWidth())/2, (screen.height - getHeight())/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. "It is important that the pack() call happens before setLocation". I put the pack() method after the setLocationRelativeto(null). That's why it didn't work. I switched it around, and now it's working. Thanks man.